# How to access key within moving nested array with ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I've managed to put together some code, which fethces json and displays it in html with the help of angular-js.

```
<div class="activity" ng-app="stream" ng-controller="streamCtrl">


<ul ng-repeat="x in myData">
<p class="author"><a href="https://hypothes.is/stream?q=user:{{x.user}}">{{x.user}}</a></p>
<p class="context_title"><a class="context" href="{{x.links.incontext}}">{{x.document.title}}</a></p>
<p class="exact">{{x.target[0].selector[2].exact}}</p>

<p class="text" btf-markdown="x.text">{{x.text}}</p>
<span ng-click="loadFromMenu($parent.$index)" ng-repeat="y in x.tags">
      <a href="https://hypothes.is/stream?q=tag:{{y}}">[{{y}}]</a>
</span>
<p class="reply"><a href="{{x.links.incontext}}">reply</a></p>
<br>
</ul>
```

Everything works fine, but I noticed that the location of the key called "exact"

```
<p class="exact">{{x.target[0].selector[2].exact}}</p>
```

within "selector" changes. Some api responses return it in the third subarray, some in the fourth .. it varies.

Here's one sample json segment - as you can see "exact" is in the third subarray within selector.

```
{
    "total": 9,
    "rows":
    [
        {
            "updated": "2016-07-19T20:46:47.509685+00:00",
            "group": "__world__",
            "target":
            [
                {
                    "source": "http://...",
                    "selector":
                    [
                        {
                            "endContainer": "/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/section[1]/div[1]/p[98]",
                            "startContainer": "/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/section[1]/div[1]/p[97]/b[1]",
                            "type": "RangeSelector",
                            "startOffset": 0,
                            "endOffset": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextPositionSelector",
                            "end": 22803,
                            "start": 22676
                        },
                        {
                            "exact": "Are ...",
                            "prefix": "esearch...",
                            "type": "TextQuoteSelector",
                            "suffix": "List of References Berkeley,"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "links":
            {
                "json": "https://..",
                "html": "https://..",
                "incontext": "https://.."
            },
            "tags":
            [
                "a",
                "b"
            ],
            "text": "They ..",
            "created": "2016-07-19T20:46:47.509677+00:00",
            "uri": "http://..",
            "user": "user",
            "document":
            {
                "title":
                [
                    "A Morning .."
                ]
            },
            "id": "6SDjLE3xEeaEfYfRR17PhA",
            "permissions":
            {
                "read":
                [
                    "group:__world__"
                ],
                "admin":
                [
                    "user"
                ],
                "update":
                [
                    "user"
                ],
                "delete":
                [
                    "user"
                ]
            }
        },
...
]}
```

My question is - what would be the best way to insure that angular always access "exact", no matter the number of arrays in "selector"?

Comment: Your JSON is incomplete.. can u post the complete code?

Comment: There's a lot of it of it, so I won't post everyting, this first bit repeats.

Comment: I mean the correct one.. because I saw you accessing `x.links` for example and I don't see any property called  `links`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right, out of all selectors of `x.target[0]` you only care for the one (could there be more than one?) with `exact` in it.

Filtering the selectors for exactly that predicate should do the job:

```html
<!-- Edit: here was a suggested answer that didn't even parse correctly. See below. -->
```

Note that [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns a list of all matching elements, so you have to pick one of the results yourself (the `[0]`).

Also note that I wrote ES5 for less confusion, using ES2015 [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) (and the fact that [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) is enough for the filter predicate) you could drill it a bot more down to

```html
<p class="exact">{{ x.target[0].selector.find(x => x.exact).exact }}</p>
```

---

*Edit: seems you can't write a `{` in the template expression without parser hick-ups.*

This can be circumvented by moving the filter predicate to the `$scope`:

```javascript
// in the controller
$scope.hasExactProperty = function(selector) {
  return selector.exact !== undefined;
};
```

```html
<!-- in the template -->
<p class="exact">{{ x.target[0].selector.filter(hasExactProperty)[0].exact }}</p>
```

Or you move the whole processing of `x` to the `$scope` (then we have more or less [Rajesh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38483006/1168892)):

```javascript
// in the controller
$scope.getExact = function(x) {
  return x.target[0].selector.filter(function(x) {
    return x.exact !== undefined;
  })[0].exact;
};
```

```html
<p class="exact">{{ getExact(x) }}</p>
```

Note that you have to assign `this.hasExactProperty`/`this.getExact` if you use the controller via `controllerAs`.

Comment: Thanks, looks very elegant, no code on the side. I get this returned in the console, though

"Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' is unexpected, expecting [)] at column 41 of the expression [x.target[0].selector.filter(function(x) { return x.exact !== undefined; })[0].exact] starting at [{ return x.exact !== undefined; })[0].exact].

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function which would loop over all `selector` to find `exact` and return its value

```js
var o = {
  "target": [{
    "source": "http://...",
    "selector": [{
      "endContainer": "/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/section[1]/div[1]/p[91]/b[1]",
      "startContainer": "/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/section[1]/div[1]/p[91]/b[1]",
      "type": "RangeSelector",
      "startOffset": 0,
      "endOffset": 266
    }, {
      "type": "TextPositionSelector",
      "end": 22559,
      "start": 22293
    }, {
      "exact": "If we consider ...",
      "prefix": " blablah. Someone:",
      "type": "TextQuoteSelector",
      "suffix": "Someone2: In filmmaking as researc"
    }]
  }]
}

function getValueInObj(obj, key) {
  return obj.target[0].selector.find(function(_o) {
    return _o[key];
  })[key];
}

console.log(getValueInObj(o, "exact"));
```

You will have to pass current object in this function:

```
<p class="exact">{{getValueInObj(x)}}</p>
```

Note: I have assumed you just need first value of exact. Also [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is not supported by IE. If you want to make it compatible, you can add [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill) or you can try [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: looks promising, will try it